# apex:slds vs lightningstylesheet option

Tags: visualforce, slds

What is the benefit of using `<apex:slds>` vs specifying the `lightningstylesheet` attribute on your `<apex:page>`?

These links talks about both but I don't understand the difference

- [apex:slds](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.pages.meta/pages/pages_compref_slds.htm)
- [Automatically Style Existing Visualforce Pages with Lightning Experience Stylesheets (Beta)](https://releasenotes.docs.salesforce.com/en-us/winter18/release-notes/rn_vf_lightningstylesheets.htm)

Does `lightningstylesheet` attribute deprecate or trump using the `<apex:slds>` tag after winter 18?

With both I see that I can inherit lightning style sheets in my page. Is one better than other (or) is there a marked difference between these options?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

When using `<apex:slds />` you are always receiving the latest version of CSS from SLDS while using the lightningStylesheets="true" does not add the SLDS stylesheets to the page, but instead changes the standard stylesheets from Visualforce to "look" like SLDS.

when using lightningStylesheets="true", Observing the network tab traffic, we clearly see that SLDS is not loaded, but instead a mock slds:

[image]
VS using the apex:slds Tag
[image]

[Style Existing Visualforce Pages with Lightning Experience Stylesheets](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.pages.meta/pages/vf_dev_best_practices_slds_lightningstylesheets.htm)

> Some components differ slightly in style from Lightning Experience.
>   For example, `<apex:selectOptions>`, `<apex:selectRadio>`,
>   `<apex:inputFile>`, and some  elements use the
>   browser’s default styling instead.

Most importantly:

> To include SLDS components that aren’t part of the Visualforce
>   component library, you can use the `<apex:slds />` tag with custom SLDS
>   code in addition to the lightningStylesheets attribute.
>   ThelightningStylesheets attribute doesn’t affect custom styling, so
>   custom code and must be updated to match the page’s SLDS styling.

So,

> lightningStylesheets="true" does not deprecate apex:slds

they can even co-exist together in the same page.

The link above contains the list of Visualforce components that support the lightningStylesheets attribute or don’t require styling.

Comment: Is that usage different between using `<apex:slds>` though versus using the `lightningstylesheet` attribute on your `<apex:page>`? It seems like you are comparing the former to uploading your own resource, rather than the new page attribute.

Comment: Apex:slds does not require static resource upload, both seem to do the same job except that apex:slds has this scoping requirement with corner cases like no suport for apex:pageblock etc.. while lightningstylesheets affect the vf page components all over with no corner cases, i wanted to know what was the reasoning behind having 2 tags that do almost same job(or atleast i assume they do the same job)

Comment: @Rao It's not two tags. It's one tag vs. one attribute. They did not introduce a new tag which does the same thing.

Comment: But dont they do the same thing apex:slds attribute and lightningstylesheet tag

Comment: @glls my bad i pasted the wrong link first time i asked the question, please relook into the updated question

Comment: if it is worth anything, i updated my post =)

Answer (score 6):

Based on currently published information, it seems like mostly personal preference. Functionally, they are stated to achieve the same goal, namely including the most recent SLDS Stylesheet.

The currently known differences:

With the `<apex:slds />` tag:

- [Earliest API Version available is 39.0](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/q/160573/2995)
- Requires you to add a tag inside your `<apex:page>`

With the `lightningStylesheets` attribute on the `<apex:page>` tag:

- Earliest API Version tested is 39.0
- Requires an attribute on your `<apex:page>`, but no additional tags

Seems like there could be some impact on Viewstate but I can't add this attribute in any of my orgs currently to test that hypothesis.

Comment: Point taken, once lightningstylesheet goes GA which would be the better option is what i am trying to understand

Comment: @Rao It does not seem to have any clear advantages. If I can enable this feature I can dig deeper but have not been able to yet.

Comment: I am very intersted to hear your observations on this question

Answer (score 3):

Use `lightningStylesheets="true"` to automatically style Visualforce/Apex markup to look like Lightning. It was created explicitly to retrofit legacy Visualforce markup with Lightning styling.

If you are using [Lightning Design System markup](http://www.lightningdesignsystem.com) in your page, add `<apex:slds>`

Ideally, if you are mixing Visualforce with SLDS markup, be sure to acutely wrap your areas of SLDS markup with `<div class="slds-scope">` as adding the `slds-scope` class to a root element of a mixed Visualforce/SLDS markup page could cause styling side effects.

As the lead author of the CSS for LightningStylesheets, hopefully this clarifies the confusion :)

Answer (score 0):

The lightningStylesheets attribute is a quick and simple way to update VF page styling to reflect Lightning.

Depending on your situation (i.e. you need to update the styling of a standard Button, etc.) you might require a more tailored approach, in which case you'd want to follow the Lightning Design System blueprint.

Specifics can be found in the Developer Guide [here](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.pages.meta/pages/vf_dev_best_practices_slds_lightningstylesheets.htm)