# apex:slds vs apex:includelightning vs apex:page lightningStylesheets="true"

Tags: visualforce, lightning, lightning-experience, lightning-design-system, slds

apex:slds vs apex:includelightning vs apex:page lightningStylesheets="true".
Which one do we need to use to enable lightning experience in existing visualforce pages?

Comment: similar to https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/195511/apexslds-vs-lightningstylesheet-option/195513#195513

Answer (score 7, accepted):

In order to automatically style your existing Visualforce pages, WITHOUT (much) CHANGING of your Visualforce code, you want the `lightningstylesheets` attribute on `apex:page`.

As long as you Visualforce pages consist mainly of `apex:sectionHeader`, `apex:pageBlock`, `apex:pageBlockSection` and the like, they should style quite nicely to LEx when rendered for a user that has LEx turned on.

`apex:slds` on the other hand requires you to completely rewrite all of your Visualforce to follow the HTML structure specified at https://lightningdesignsystem.com/

Also, when using `apex:slds`, the appearance of the page will be equivalent for Classic users and LEx users; the HTML you have to author will not automatically switch to match the mode that the user is in

Comment: What is the usecase of apex:includelightning

Comment: If you're using Lightning Components in your VF page, you need to get the Lightning Component runtime necessary for Lighting Out (see https://developer.salesforce.com/blogs/developer-relations/2016/02/lightning-components-visualforce-lightning.html for a relevant article on Lightning Out)

Answer (score 5):

I'm a Visualforce platform developer within Salesforce. I view each option on a spectrum of how much time and effort you are able to put in.

1. `lightningStylesheets="true"` -- Super easy to turn on, almost no testing required because it's just a stylesheet change. This is best used for Visualforce apps that you want to look better in Lightning, but don't plan on spending a lot of future effort maintaining.
2. `<apex:slds/>` -- Also "just" a stylesheet, but a very picky stylesheet. It requires your page to have the [markup specified by SLDS](http://lightningdesignsystem.com), which means you have to change the page. So you'll have to change and test the Visualforce page, but *probably* don't have to change the Apex controller code. This is a half-way point to writing Lightning components.
3. `<apex:includeLightning/>` -- Much more than a stylesheet, this brings in the CSS and controller for Lightning components. If you make a complex Lightning app, you can include it in a Visualforce page just for users in Salesforce Classic. It's also good for changing parts of an app at a time -- if you change a page piece by piece, once the entire page is Lightning, you can just delete the page and make it a Lightning tab.