# Use LightningStylesheets=true on Lightning Community

Tags: lightning-experience, lightning-community, lightningstylesheets

We are developing a new Lightning Community to replace our Partner Community. However, when we use our visualforce pages with `LightningStylesheets=true` on the Lightning Community, the Lightning styling is not applied.

I understand that this is the case because Lightning Communities are not Lightning Experience.

Is there a way to force LightningStylesheets anyway? I am trying to stay away from having to rebuild/restyle all our legacy visualforce pages.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

[LightningStylesheets](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.pages.meta/pages/vf_dev_best_practices_slds_lightningstylesheets.htm)=true has limitations and will try to style your page as close as it can to SLDS, however, it does not support all apex:tags, I would suggest you read [apex:slds vs lightningstylesheet option](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/195511/apexslds-vs-lightningstylesheet-option) which explains in more detail the difference.

Without your VF page code, we cant really suggest the best approach either.

Comment: Actually adding the apex:slds tag more or less did the trick. I was expecting I'd have to style individual elements as well, but that's not necessary. It applies a general Lighting look&feel automatically. Only thing is that it is not conditional, so it shows the page in Lightning look&feel even for Classic users. But I was able to solve that with a rendered tag.

Comment: good stuff =), cheers!

Comment: Hi Guy, did your code have apex:pageBlock, apex:PageBlockTables, apex:PageBlockSections, apex:InputField ? I try to do the same cause it is shown in classic UI in Partner community, but applying the apex:slds tag does not solve my problem. Could you please share a code snippet in order to get an idea? Thanks