# Lightning Design Classes Not Included on Visualforce page

Tags: visualforce, lightning, slds, design

I am using the lightning design system for creating a visualforce page. However some classes are not included in the slds.css.

I have copied and pasted a 'Setup assistant' from the lightning design system and lot of the styling classes are missing.

In the visualforce page I have included:

```
<apex:page lightningStylesheets="true">
<apex:slds />
```

Any idea how I can apply these styles?

The only alternative is copying the styles individually from the lightning design system website, but hoping there's a better way!

Comment: Give [`apex:slds`](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/195511/apexslds-vs-lightningstylesheet-option) a try?

Comment: Yeah apex:slds is included :)

Comment: Do not include both at same time, issue persists with both of them?

Comment: Make sure checkbox "Available for Lightning Experience, Lightning Communities, and the mobile app" is checked given on VF page defintion...

Comment: I have tried both tags individually - same results. I have also checked the lightning experience box.

Answer (score 0):

Setup Assistant is a new component in v2.6 (Summer '18) of the Lightning Design System.

Try updating the API version on your Visualforce page to 42 or 43 (Summer '18). The SLDS version of the CSS imported with  is currently set to v2.3 for pages with API versions up through 41. From API v42 and above, the latest SLDS CSS version is served.