# Visualforce page in Partner Communities shown in Classic UI

Tags: visualforce, partner-communities, lightningstylesheets

I have implemented some VF Pages that use lightningStylesheets="true". As internal user, the page is displayed properly, however when i log in as a Partner user, the pages are shown with the classic UI. Has anyone faced this issue? Any suggestions on how i can overcome it?
Screenshots below:
Internal user:
[image]

Partner user:
[image]

Answer (score 1):

Can you try the approach mentioned in the [article](https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=000314958&type=1&mode=1) and see if it fixes the issue

> Visualforce pages using lightningStylesheets="true" and that display with Classic styling in Lightning Experience are a result of the UserPreferencesLightningExperiencePreferred field for the user experiencing the behavior. In order to check the value for that field on a User record, you can use the following steps.
>
> 1. As a System Admin user, run the following query in the Developer Console or Workbench: `SELECT UserPreferencesLightningExperiencePreferred, Id, Username FROM User where id = 'userId'`
> 2. Check if the result of the query shows the UserPreferencesLightningExperiencePreferred field value as "false"
> 3. When the field value is false, Visualforce pages with lightningStylesheets="true" will use Classic styling in Lightning
>    Experience
>
> This field value will usually change when users use the Lightning
> Experience Switcher to change between Salesforce Classic and Lightning
> Experience. If the user's Profile has the "Hide Option to Switch to
> Salesforce Classic" permission enabled, you will need to use the
> Salesforce Dataloader or a similar tool to update their User record to
> update their preferred UI experience.

Comment: Hi Swetha and thank you for your response. The field value at user level is set to "true". :( I suppose something has to do with the managed package from which this VF Page is invoked. I have a managed package that invokes my custom VF Page. When in Salesforce (Internal user) it pops-up in LEX, when in Community, it pops up Classic UI. So i will ask them for support...

Comment: Great! Let me know how it goes...

Comment: Hi Swetha, unfortunately, this is a Salesforce issue. In fact, lightningStylesheets isn's supported in Experience Cloud Sites. https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.pages.meta/pages/vf_dev_best_practices_slds_lightningstylesheets.htm. I think i should reconstruct all the VF Pages and use the apex:slds option. https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/195511/apexslds-vs-lightningstylesheet-option